# how do I programmatically create instance of react component?

Tags: reactjs, components, instantiation

I have a table row component that checks to see if a custom component is specified and is supposed to programmatically take that React component (`column.customComponent`) and render the data using it. However, I cannot seem to instantiate the components.. all I get is the data as a string.

Here is what I have:

```
const cellContent = typeof(column.customComponent === 'undefined') ?
  rowData[column.columnName] :
  {
    type: column.customComponent,
    props: {
      data: rowData[column.columnName],
      rowData
    }
  };
```

`console.log(cellContent);` *displays something like:*
[the function representation of the React component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y2DFG.png)
or
`function DateCell() ....`

I'm not sure if I'm just using the [wrong syntax](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/12/18/react-components-elements-and-instances.html) when assigning `cellContent` or if I should be doing something with factories or what.
How should I do this?

Comment: What exactly is `column.customComponent`? A component or a string? You probably just want to call `React.createElement(...)` directly.

Comment: @FelixKling `column.customComponent` is the the actual component I want to display. I just cannot get it instantiated.

Comment: `React.createElement(column.customComponent, {data: ..., rowData})` should work just fine...

Comment: that did it, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I use this helper method to create components and return the instance.

```
static async renderComponentAt(componentClass, props, parentElementId){
         let componentId = props.id;
        if(!componentId){
            throw Error('Component has no id property. Please include id:"...xyz..." to component properties.');
        }

        let parentElement = document.getElementById(parentElementId);

        return await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            props.ref = (component)=>{
                if(component){
                    resolve(component);
                }                    
            };
            let element = React.createElement(componentClass, props, null);
            ReactDOM.render(element, parentElement);
        });
    }
```